# Questions regarding appexchange publishing and security review

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, security-review

- Is a technical review required before submitting a managed package for security review?
- Do I need to provide an architecture documentation for the app?
- If my app changes between the security review process and publishing on the appexchange , do I need to submit again for the review?
- Can I start upgrading/patching my package (with minor changes) as soon as it is listed on appexchange? Also if I plan to change the look and feel of some visualforce pages, would that be allowed?
- I'm clueless about licensing. I do have permission sets for different kinds of users in the app. How do I link the permission sets with licenses?
- A last question, do I need to test my application on all salesforce editions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a technical review required before submitting a managed package for security review?

> Yes it is required if your application is not straight and simple .A salesforce Technical Evangelist will get in touch with the key technical contact person indicated by you when you submit an application for review .They primarily ensure that you are not building something that salesforce provides OOB or you are not working on something that has security threats linked to SFDC echo system

Do I need to provide an architecture documentation for the app?

> Its not a mandatory step but its good to have a TDD ready .This can come handy for various other purposes as well apart from security review

If my app changes between the security review process and publishing on the appexchange , do I need to submit again for the review?

> There is an automated check that happens and it says whether your application passed or failed automatically .If it fails SFDC will contact you and you will need to fix the security vulnerabilities

Can I start upgrading/patching my package (with minor changes) as soon as it is listed on appexchange?

> Yes surely you can .

Also if I plan to change the look and feel of some visualforce pages, would that be allowed?

> Surely thats allowed and totally fine

I'm clueless about licensing. I do have permission sets for different kinds of users in the app. How do I link the permission sets with licenses?

> You can assign the permission set with a best guess license for now .Once you discover more use cases you can create more permission sets and provide an upgraded package to the customer .Also note that the subscriber also will have ability to allocate license via profiles and permission sets once your application is installed

do I need to test my application on all salesforce editions?

> Its recommended to test your application on all supported editions you want your application to run but not a mandate .Lets say you wish to not support PE edition then you can mention that your app does not support and you need not test it .Similarly if you think your app works for EE edition its safe to assume it will run for unlimited and you can skip testing .

Comment: Thats a very thorough reply. Much appreciated. Thank you taking out the time to answer it!